# Add a column to a dataframe whose value is based on another field, but needs to increment

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem I've been wrestling with and I have to imagine there is a more elegant solution than looping through my dataframe row by row.  I have a dataframe like the following:

```
          EventTime | ConditionMet

--------- --------- | --------
2017-09-11 00:00:01 | 0
2017-09-11 00:00:02 | 0
2017-09-11 00:00:03 | 0
2017-09-11 00:00:04 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:05 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:06 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:07 | 0
2017-09-11 00:00:08 | 0
2017-09-11 00:00:09 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:10 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:11 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:12 | 1
2017-09-11 00:00:13 | 0
```

Each time the condition is met (`ConditionMet=1`), I want to label the records with an event name (e.g. Event1).  I can't find an elegant way to do with `.withColumn()` using a `when` condition or with windowing.  The ideal result would be:

```
        EventTime   |ConditionMet|EventName
----------------- - | ---------- | --------
2017-09-11 00:00:01 |       0    |     
2017-09-11 00:00:02 |       0    |
2017-09-11 00:00:03 |       0    |
2017-09-11 00:00:04 |       1    | Event1
2017-09-11 00:00:05 |       1    | Event1
2017-09-11 00:00:06 |       1    | Event1
2017-09-11 00:00:07 |       0    |
2017-09-11 00:00:08 |       0    |
2017-09-11 00:00:09 |       1    | Event2
2017-09-11 00:00:10 |       1    | Event2
2017-09-11 00:00:11 |       1    | Event2
2017-09-11 00:00:12 |       1    | Event2
2017-09-11 00:00:13 |       0    |
```

Interested in any clever approaches here.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Is this really a single huge table with a single event numbering sequence? Or is it the end-product of a bunch of aggregation that could maybe pulled out into a pandas DF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if the idea is to tag each sequential cluster with a unique tag then you can do this by calculating the cumulative sum

1. Sort df, on `EventTime` for example
2. invert `ConditionMet`
3. Calculate cumulative sum of the inverted column
4. Ignore cumulative sum for `ConditionMet` = 0, and take cumulative sum as a tag of the cluster for `ConditionMet` = 1

   ```
   +-------------------+------------+-------+-------------+---------+
   |          EventTime|ConditionMet|InvCond|CumulativeSum|EventName|
   +-------------------+------------+-------+-------------+---------+
   |2017-09-11 00:00:01|           0|      1|            1|         |
   |2017-09-11 00:00:02|           0|      1|            2|         |
   |2017-09-11 00:00:03|           0|      1|            3|         |
   |2017-09-11 00:00:04|           1|      0|            3|   Event3|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:05|           1|      0|            3|   Event3|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:06|           1|      0|            3|   Event3|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:07|           0|      1|            4|         |
   |2017-09-11 00:00:08|           0|      1|            5|         |
   |2017-09-11 00:00:09|           1|      0|            5|   Event5|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:10|           1|      0|            5|   Event5|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:11|           1|      0|            5|   Event5|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:12|           1|      0|            5|   Event5|
   |2017-09-11 00:00:13|           0|      1|            6|         |
   +-------------------+------------+-------+-------------+---------+
   ```

Code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, udf, col
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

def tagSequentialClusters(df, condColumn, tagColumnName):
    ## Invert condition 0 will be 1 and 1 will be 0
    def InvCond(value):
        if value == '1':
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    ## Add Event for the valid clusters
    def mapEventNumber(cond, number):
        if cond == "1":
            return "Event" + str(number)
        else:
            return ""

    ## Add new columns to row
    def addRowColumn(row, **kwargs):
        rowData = row.asDict()
        for column in kwargs:
            rowData[column] = kwargs[column]
        return Row(**rowData)

    ## Calculate partial cumulative sum for partition iterator
    def calcPartialCumulativeSum(iter):
        counter = 0     
        final_iterator = []
        for row in iter:
            counter = counter + row["InvCond"]
            newRow = addRowColumn(row, PartialSum=counter)
            final_iterator.append(newRow)
        return final_iterator

    ## get tail of partiton with index
    def getTailWithIndex(index, iter): 
        tailRow = None
        for row in iter:
            tailRow = row
        return (index, tailRow["PartialSum"])

    ## Calculate sum map for each partition
    def calcSumMap(collectedMap):
        final_iterator = {}
        for index, value in enumerate(collectedMap):
            newVal = value
            for i in range(0, index):
                newVal += collectedMap[i]
            final_iterator[index] = newVal
        return final_iterator

    ## Calculate global cumulative sum
    def calcCumulativeSum(index, iter):
        final_iterator = []
        for row in iter:
            newVal = row["PartialSum"] + sumMap.value[index]
            final_iterator.append(addRowColumn(row, EventNumber=newVal))
        return final_iterator

    ## Register udf functions
    invCondUdf = udf(InvCond, IntegerType())
    mapEventNumberUdf = udf(mapEventNumber, StringType())

    ## Invert ConditionMet column
    rdd = df.withColumn("InvCond", invCondUdf(col(condColumn))).rdd

    ## Calculate partial cumulative sum over each partition
    rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: calcPartialCumulativeSum(iter)).cache()

    ## Calculate max sum value for each partition
    collctedMap = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(getTailWithIndex).collect()
    sumMap = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(calcSumMap(collctedMap))

    ## Calculate global cumulative sum 
    df = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(calcCumulativeSum).toDF()

    ## Append `Event` before each cluster number and ignore the rest
    df = df.withColumn(tagColumnName, mapEventNumberUdf(col(condColumn), col("EventNumber")))

    return df.drop(col("EventNumber")).drop(col("InvCond")).drop(col("PartialSum"))

## Read data
df = spark.read.csv("/home/eslam-elbanna/data.csv", header=True)    

## Tag sequnetial clusters
df = tagSequentialClusters(df, "ConditionMet", "EventName")
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('EventName', F.when(df["ConditionMet"]>0.0, "Event1").otherwise("")
```

Comment: Correct Matt.  Getting the Event label to increment (e.g. Event1, Event2, etc.) is the challenge I am having...

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution to my problem, although I don't know how elegant it is.  Essentially, I joined the dataset back to itself by the timestamp on the previous record (I supposed a lead() function could've helped me with this.  From there, I could pass in the current condition and the next condition to determine change (and that is when I increment the global counter used in the EventName creation.  Code below.

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, expr, when
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array

cnt=0

def tagTrip(t):
     global cnt
     if t[0]==1:
         if t[1]==0:
             cnt=cnt+1
         return "Event" + str(cnt)
     else:
        return ""

tagTripUdf = udf(lambda arr: tagTrip(arr), StringType())

# I don't include the code that shows how I got to this df and how I can join it onto itself
dfJoined = df.join(dfNext, df['time'] == dfNext['timeprev'], 'inner')

dfNew=dfJoined.withColumn('EventName',tagTripUdf(array(col('ConditionMet'),col('ConditionMetNext'))))
```